# How to convert hex string in C# to hex string in java

Tags: c#, java, string, hex, converters

Convert from byte[] array to hex string in C# and Java gives us different result. 
Here is hex String in C#:

`text1 ="30818902818100930033856fc39d6dd5ebd53829ac6f55895aceb08bf0f026aa0eaa0f87078204e4083a97a9eb8a08c72f14aa8b369e279e3eaf55409c7f0d05cce68a170f1b5746ba162502c327406762da51f6698213c3c7e88294ac3362d74a244ddb632c4835c5bc75449924fb1004b1e14f8ddc581c97718a74cac6c292c86079c3352f0f0203010001"`

(Actually, `text1` is public key string copied from **.cer** file)

And here is the hex String in Java:

`text2 
="30819f300d06092a864886f70d010101050003818d0030818902818100de5e8945c6451d2d9d37e395adfdd7e924f341bbd096f875a7093b59f1f76f46d64e0bccf103e7ad813b0012c83c3bd8c512e8ecc82d59f55bff02479ae17f917d49f58a7731e9288a53c4a95e68f8aedaef8cd5b790340c18cb2d87b3d5248d97caaafe3c0cea74cf258d7adc103c6c0143639f9235c1e368324e32d6aa4aef0203010001"`

I cannot change my partner code in C#, so what I have to do is convert that text1 to text2. 
Do anyone here can suggest me how to do that?

Or how can I get Public Key from `text1`, it always give me the wrong format. That's why I have to use text2.
Thanks

Comment: Would be better if we saw both C# and Java code you used..

Comment: I strongly suspect that the byte arrays you've started with are different. However, you haven't told us anything about where the data comes from (beyond "copied from .cer file", which doesn't tell us much) , or what code you're using to convert from `byte[]` to text on either platform.